# Compile error: Cannot find symbol Suspend and AsynchronousResponse

Tags: maven, jax-rs, resteasy, camunda

I'm trying to use asynchronous HTTP request processing feature with RESTEasy in a Camunda BPM example project (embedded-spring-rest). To test if existing [pom file](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/blob/master/deployment/embedded-spring-rest/pom.xml) is okay, I put import statements for `Suspend` and `AsynchronousResponse` in `RestProcessEngineDeployment.java`. But the maven compile failed.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project camunda-quickstart-embedded-spring-rest: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/vagrant/works/eclipse-workspace/camunda-bpm-examples/deployment/embedded-spring-rest/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/example/loanapproval/rest/RestProcessEngineDeployment.java:[7,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Suspend
[ERROR] location: package javax.ws.rs
[ERROR] /home/vagrant/works/eclipse-workspace/camunda-bpm-examples/deployment/embedded-spring-rest/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/example/loanapproval/rest/RestProcessEngineDeployment.java:[8,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class AsynchronousResponse
[ERROR] location: package javax.ws.rs.core
```

The [POM file](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/blob/master/deployment/embedded-spring-rest/pom.xml) looks okay. It contains the necessary dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The [web.xml file](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/blob/master/deployment/embedded-spring-rest/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) also looks okay. It contains `filter` and `filter-mapping` as is suggested in [RESTEasy user guide](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.7.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#filter).

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Resteasy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.FilterDispatcher
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.camunda.bpm.example.loanapproval.rest.RestProcessEngineDeployment</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>Resteasy</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Did I miss anything? Any clue as to how I can figure out the problem?

Comment: Maybe you want [`javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse.html) and [`@javax.ws.rs.container.Suspended`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/Suspended.html). Hard to tell without seeing some code.

Comment: @peeskillet, You are right! I put wrong import statements. I should have noticed that the import statements and the actual interface/annotation used are different in [RESTEasy user guide](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#Asynchronous_HTTP_Request_Processing).

Comment: @peeskillet would you please put the comment as an answer.I would like to accept the answer. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was hard to tell without seeing code but the Maven error was a pretty good signal.  I just couldn't figure out why anyone would be using `AsynchronousResponse` and `Suspend`. Seeing your [link in the comment](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#Asynchronous_HTTP_Request_Processing) makes perfect sense now. Here's a snippet from the link

```
import javax.ws.rs.Suspend;
import javax.ws.rs.core.AsynchronousResponse;

@Path("/")
public class SimpleResource {
   @GET
   @Path("basic")
   @Produces("text/plain")
   public void getBasic(@Suspended final AsyncResponse response)
```

The sad thing is, the author even switches between `AsyncResponse` and `AsynchronousResponse` in the description.

Anyway, the error can be solved by using the correct imports:

- [`import javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse;`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse.html) and
- [`import javax.ws.rs.container.Suspended;`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/Suspended.html)